# Find second occurence from the right of a character, without iteration

Tags: python, string, indexing

I have a Python string:

```
test = 'blablabla_foo_bar_baz'
```

I want the negative index of the second occurence **from the right** of `_`: in this case, this would be -8, but even 13, the positive index, would be an acceptable answer, because it's not hard to compute the negative index from the positive index. How can I do that? A GPT-4 solution uses `rfind` + iteration, but I was wondering if it could be possible to solve it in one shot, without iteration. Of course the answer should handle strings of arbitrary length, and it should match an arbitrary character (`_` in this example).

EDIT: I need the negative index of the second occurence from the right of `_`, because I want to strip away `_bar_baz`, which can be done easily with

```
test_prefix = test[:-8]
```

Thus, alternative solutions that allow me to get `test_prefix` without first finding the negative index of the second occurence from the right of `_`, would also be ok. Using the length of the substring `_bar_baz` (8 in this case) is **not** ok because I don't know the length of this substring. Instead computing the length of the substring from the second occurrence from the right of `_`, until the end of the string, would be ok. It doesn't seem any different from computing he negative index of the second occurence from the right of `_`, though.

EDIT2: a commenter says that it's impossible to solve this without iteration. I'm not sure they're right, but I'll show a (GPT-4-generated) example of what I *don't* want:

```
def find_second_last_occurrence(text, char='_'):
    last_occurrence = text.rfind(char)

    second_last_occurrence = text.rfind(char, 0, last_occurrence)

    return second_last_occurrence

string = "blablabla_foo_bar_baz"
result = find_second_last_occurrence(string, '_')

print(result)  # Output: 20
```

In this case, we had to call `rfind` twice. Is this really necessary? I don't think all possible solutions (including those based on `re`, `rsplit`, etc.) require calling a builtin twice. **Note** that I didn't include any code checking for the occurence of `_` in the string, because I know for sure that my input string contains at least two occurences of `_`.

Comment: `solve it in one shot, without iteration` anything with a string will use iteration at least once if not just to put it in a new data structure. You can reduce the number of iterations or do it with a partial iteration by using a dict lookup table and iterating it backwards (which r_find does), but regardless, strings will at least require partial iteration (even with RegEx). Is the question just about trying to get the fastest possible solution?

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse read it as "without _explicit_ iteration". I will add the GPT-4 solution for clarity. "Fastest solution" could be ok, but for such a simple task I'm not sure comparing speeds is easy (cache hits will mask most optimizations). Maybe "simplest solution"?

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse what I meant is that I didn't want to call a builtin (such as, for example, `rfind`) twice. I don't believe all possible solutions need to call a Python function from the standard library twice

Comment: Looks like we all built a solution around a `split`, though I realized we don't return `-1` (or should it be 1 in this case?) for strings with less than 2 underscores.

Comment: @MichaelCao note my second edit: _[..] I didn't include any code checking for the occurence of _ in the string, because I know for sure that my input string contains at least two occurences of _._

Comment: I'm not sure if you are excluding regular expressions, but `test = re.sub('_[^_]*_[^_]*$', '', test)` does the job and I think its quite straight forward to read later.

Comment: @tdelaney I'm not excluding them, but I already chose the answer. Anyway, if you write yours and explain how it works, I'll happily upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure the exact solution that is wanted but if the goal is just to split the string there is a much cleaner approach which can also give you the index it was cut at.

```py
test = 'blablabla_foo_bar_baz'
result, *_ = test.rsplit('_', maxsplit=2) # split from the right two times
print(result) # blablabla_foo
print(len(result)) # 13 which is the index it was cut off at
print(len(test) - len(result)) # 8 i.e. the negative index
```

Comment: just a minor correction: the negative index is `len(result) - len(test)`, not `len(test) - len(result)`

Comment: I left it positive to show the number of characters cut off. Technically, it would be flipped if you wanted a negative number.

Answer (score 1):

Use split and then calculate the index based on the length of the splits.

```
sum(map(len, test.split("_")[-2:])) + 2
```

Answer (score 1):

With `str.rsplit` + `str.join`:

```
test = 'blablabla_foo_bar_baz'
pos = -(len(''.join(test.rsplit('_', 2)[-2:])) + 2)
print(pos)
```

---

```
-8
```

Answer (score 1):

While this problem is much better solved with `.rsplit()`, here's a regex solution (strongly discouraged):

```py
import re

def find_nth_last_index(string, char, n):
    escaped_char = re.escape(char)
    regex = re.compile(f'({escaped_char}[^{escaped_char}]*){{{n}}}$')
    return -len(regex.search(string).group())
```

Try it:

```py
test = 'blablabla_foo_bar_baz'

print(find_nth_last_index(test, '_', 2))  # -8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a regular expression that matches the stuff you want to remove. `re.sub` will replace that match with the string of your choice, notably `""`.

```
import re

test = 'blablabla_foo_bar_baz'
expected_result = 'blablabla_foo'
test = re.sub('_[^_]*_[^_]*$', '', test)
print(test == expected_result, repr(test))
```

In the regex, `[^_]*` matches any number of non-underscores and `$` matches the end of the string. So it will find `_foo_bar` but only at the end of the string